# Mysql select speed

Tags: mysql, ajax

I have a problem with a speed of mysql query.
I have 2 select boxes with country and cities, on first select changes cities on the second, its provided by ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$(".country").change(function()
{
var id=$(this).val(); 
var dataString = 'id='+ id;
function doAJAX(url) {

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: url,

data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$(".city").html(html); 
}

});
}




doAJAX('search_ajax.php');
});
});
```

When is for example spain or russia where is so many cities, showing them took too much time, table cities:fips 2 varchar, city varchar 100, 
my select :

```
SELECT city from cities where fips='some value' //for example EN or any ..
```

I have on column fips index.

Can anobody help mi to speed this up? or is a better solution other than ajax to make live change of select's?? thanks

Comment: Have you actually profiled it to prove that the query itself is slow rather than some other part of the system?

Comment: with profiled it, you meant the time that spend query on the system? I've found percona-toolkit, but it's not running on Windows, and in show status, I don't know how to read it :(

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an index on column `fips`.

Comment: I've entered that on column fips is index

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it could be marked as a solution, but I solved it by adding a loading gif when its requested from mysql, maybe it will help someone, the function changes to:

```
function doAJAX(url) {
    $(".city").hide(); // hide the select
    $("#Div1").show(); // show loading gif
    $("#Div1").html('<img src="images/loading2.gif"> Loading...'); 
    $.ajax({   
        type: "POST",
        url: url,    
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $(".city").html(html);
            $(".city").show(); // on succes show select
            $("#Div1").hide(); // and hide the loading
        }
    });
}
```