# ajax speed of generating select

Tags: mysql, ajax, performance

I had a question here [Mysql select speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368092/mysql-select-speed)
I figure that select of mysql is fast, but

My problem is when the ajax is generating a huge select and option of cities, for example BRAZIL.

Is there a way to generate the ajax select faster? Because if it's too big, the browser lag and waits to load full content of select. I want it smoother.
Can anyone help me please ? :(

Comment: Is you problem is in server or in client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cache your query result. That means, run the query on a regular base, save the result (for example in another table or in an xml file), then send the precached data to the browser on request.

Comment: u mean: have prepared the list of cities in external file and then load it into div?

Comment: Yes, for example. The other option would be to save the query to a mysql view, though I am not an expert in mysql and do not know if using mysql views has similar performance advantages like the materialized view of oracle.

Comment: well, I've tried preload it, I send ajax request and wirte it into file for example form.html, then I load it into some div, when I tried it in blank page it's fast, but when I load it into my full page, it took too long, where is the problem??

Comment: Then the problem may just be the sheer amount of data (in another comment you were talking about 2.5 million rows). Maybe you have a slow computer and your browser is having problems including the data on your page. Try to change your browser or try another pc to see if the problem persists and to eliminate potential causes for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to preload the whole lists into your document and hide them by the `display: none;` property. Then you do not need to AJAX pull the contents of your select box. Instead, just show the list you need if a user selects a specific entry and hide the others.

Comment: hm, that's possible solution but, I have a big database of cities all over the world, load it into document will spend much time to load the page, isn't it?

Comment: about 2,5 milion rows, -> cities

Comment: You could check which countries are the most used and preload only the most popular ones. For the others you can use a caching method as [user1039665](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8256044/675065) suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Is you problem is in server or in client? 
Fiddler or Firebug can help you to know how much time spent by processing in server and by transfering to client.

I think you need to change your server side, and return small strings, like this:

```
1,Jerusalem|2,Tel Aviv|3,Ariel
```

In client side, you need to split by "|" and then by ",", and use an JS array to build HTML:

```
    //not tested

    var a = string.split("|"),s=[]
    for (var i=0;i"+b[1]+"");
    }

    $("#div").html(s.join(" "));
```

JSON is easier to use, but will make the response larger and slowly.